# How do we tag DayZ?

Tags: discussion, tags

DayZ standalone is in public early access. It has lots of similarities with the mod but it's still a different game. How do we tag the standalone and the mod? We currently only have questions about the mod.

The current situation tag-wise is that we have [dayz](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/dayz) for the mod and [dayz-standalone](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/dayz-standalone).

Answer (score 16):

I feel like [dayz-standalone](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/dayz-standalone) is a horrible way to name a tag and propose we do the following:

- [dayz](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/dayz) becomes [arma-2-dayz](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/arma-2-dayz) (DLC tagging scheme)
- [dayz-standalone](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/dayz-standalone) becomes [dayz](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/dayz)

Comment: We generally use '->' arrows to denote synonyms, I'm assuming you mean [tag] becomes [tag2]?

Comment: @Robotnik You are correct

Comment: Cool. (More chars)

Comment: I would propose to use [dayz-alpha], so questions about the game which is currently under heavy development can be filtered after it reaches beta or release status.

Answer (score -11):

As usual:

- [dayz-2012](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/dayz-2012)
- [dayz-2013](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/dayz-2013)